# Describing the Difference Between Web Library and Web Framework

Tags: web-development, frameworks, libraries

I talked myself into a hole at work, and I need some good ideas to help me better describe why we should include both [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/hello_dojo/demo/slideInGreeting.html) **and** [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html) in our new web project.

A little background: I do mostly computer-computer interactions when I program; updating states, reading/writing to the database -- Knockout is exactly where I want to be.

So I said, "I don't want to use Dojo"...meaning, "I don't want to do client side user experience/visual effects programming". I think it's a great to utilize other people's work, and I think re-inventing the wheel is a bad thing, generally. I just don't enjoy the process as much. But now its turned into an "all or nothing" decision.

Please help me come up with a good way to describe the difference between a library and a web framework, and not [in this technical way](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54451/library-vs-framework-vs-api). I need something simpler to get my point across.

Answer (score 3):

The Design Patterns and the OO movement guys had a definition along the lines of:

*An application uses parts of a library, and provides the missing parts in a framework.*

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is a framework in which the user provides a data model, page templates, and URL routing information to have a working Web Application. [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is a library for manipulating images in Python.

Comment: Im sorry to say this but I used the dreaded "D" word to relate Knockout to an MTV framework. Apparently that was a trigger for my boss. +1 for going where I did! `:D`

Comment: +1, but I like: "A library is the code that your code calls. Your code is the library the framework calls."

Comment: +1...I said...look at the `<script src='http://....>`...notice how it's on the web? That's typical of libraries. Frameworks? You store those in your project (they don't do a lot of things outside of their sole purpose - linking DOM-things to OO-things, and eventually tables.