# Why is JUnit called a Framework?

Tags: architecture, terminology, libraries, frameworks, junit

Citing [JUnits homepage](http://junit.org/): "JUnit is a simple framework to write repeatable tests. It is an instance of the xUnit architecture for unit testing frameworks."

According to a the answer of this question: [Library vs. framework vs API?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54451/library-vs-framework-vs-api), a framework is "a collection of patterns and libraries to help with building an application" and library is defined as "a collection of functions / objects that serves one particular purpose. you could use a library in a variety of projects".

As a framework is said to have collection of libraries, why is junit called a framework and not a library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Library vs. framework vs API?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/54451/library-vs-framework-vs-api)

Comment: @gnat: I updated my question, with more detail.

Comment: Top comment on the answer you cite: "That's not a very good definition of a framework.". Look at the other comments and the others answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple rule of thumb that many use for whether to call something a library or framework is:

1. Does the external code call your code, ie does the external code control your code? Is yes, it's a framework.
2. Does the external code only get called by your code (ignoring callbacks), ie does your code control the external code? Is yes, it's a library.

"Tool" is a very generic term that could be applied to all frameworks, libraries, apps, APIs, SDKs etc, so probably isn't a good choice of term for JUnit.